# React native release version build fails with D8: Program type already present: com.reactnativecommunity.webview.BuildConfig

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

In a React native project that I work on, I want to use `react-native-webview` for showing some HTML content on a view.

After adding the package `react-native-webview`, `gradlew buildRelease` started failing with the following error message;

Executed command is `.\gradlew bundleRelease`

Output is

```
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED
D8: Program type already present: com.reactnativecommunity.webview.BuildConfig
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
Program type already present: com.reactnativecommunity.webview.BuildConfig
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
        at 
.....

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the `react-native-webview` package is also included by `com.facebook.react` package. Excluding the package coming from this package resolves the problem.

You need to add the following in `app/build.gradle` file

```
exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-webview'
```

Answer (score 0):

edit file in app/build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && requested.name != 'multidex') {
            details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't solve the problem.There was no entry for `configurations.all` and I added to the file but didn't solve the problem.